# can anyone point me towards the math behind biquad antennas?

Tags: antenna, wifi, math

I've looked everywhere for the equations to build a biquad antenna. Calculators are nice, but I want the math. Just point me In the right direction since I've had zero luck on Google.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations

Comment: You may want clean  rules how to calculate things like impedance (=R+jX), directivity and losses from material and dimensions.  Unfortunately many antennas are created by intuition - like the Quad to prevent harmful corona discharges at the ends of yagi antenna rods. The best dimensions for certain frequency and beam are found experimentally or by making simulations (=solving wave equations in 3D space around a given structure) Generally no exact formulas exist.  Coarse formulas can be given, you find them in antenna handbooks. You can also pick the used formulas from calculation spreadsheets.

Comment: You got a link to Maxwell's equations. That's the math behind all practical electricity including antennas. A gigantic amount of work is done to use them practically in different very limited cases such as electric circuits. The whole circuit theory is one application. Antennas unfortunately are complex and cannot be calculated by using some nice and simple laws like Ohm's and Kirchoff's laws. See one academic work which is based on simulations: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/BIQUAD-ANTENNA-SIMULATION-BANDWIDTH-SWR_fig3_308960731

Comment: There is nothing to the biquad anyway. Each edge of the square is 0.25 * wavelength. Not much else you need to know. The reflector should be around 0.125* wavelength behind the radiating element. What math would you want besides that?

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of math in antenna design: partial differential equations (PDE), linear algebra, numerical methods, to name a few. Because your question is primarily about quad antennas and not about boundary conditions or material equations, I start my answer not with Maxwell's equations, but with a reference to an article [Review of Amateur-Built 2.4-GHz Wireless-LAN Directional Wire Antennas](https://www.thaiscience.info/Journals/Article/AUJT/10568927.pdf) by Virach Wongpaibool. Whether there is or is not similarity of this review's Biquad Antenna section designs with your project, the description specifies the context of the biquad antenna design and shows design drawings and directivity gain graphs.

We read in the text that the polar plots of normalized gain are obtained with the help of the **4NEC2** software. This application is developed on the basis of the **[Numerical Electromagnetics Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_Electromagnetics_Code)**, a popular antenna modeling system for wire and surface antennas. In the Wiki article we read that the **NEC** code is based on the **method of moments (MoM)** solution of the **electric field integral equation (EFIE)** for **thin wires** and the **magnetic field integral equation (MFIE)** for closed, conducting surfaces. The text also mentions, but does not specify, numerical methods, which we will see later in the section [Currents on Linear Antennas](https://eceweb1.rutgers.edu/%7Eorfanidi/ewa/ch24.pdf) from the book of Sophocles J. Orfanidis.

You can peek ahead to this ref to see a lot of linear algebra there. For now, we return to the EM theory.

The biquad antenna is essentially a few (8?) thin wire edges. We partition those into N thin wire segments (N→∞) and use the electric field integral equation in numerical computations. There is many textbooks and courses on the solution of Maxwell's equations. For an EE student working on the antenna project, the book [Electromagnetic Waves and Antennas](https://eceweb1.rutgers.edu/%7Eorfanidi/ewa/) by Sophocles J. Orfanidis may be recommended.

The Wiki article also mentions a domain specific language (DSL) of [NEC input files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_Electromagnetics_Code#Example). Significance of the NEC file format for practical antenna design is similar to SPICE for circuit and VLSI designs. Strictly speaking, the DSL thing is not math, but computer science, but still deserves to be mentioned in the context of antenna design concepts and tooling.

The NEC modeling program is a de facto standard of CAD for antenna design software. As many antenna structures can be approximated by wires, the NEC code is based on the method of moments (MoM) solution for thin wires. Two commonly used thin-wire equations are Pocklington and Hallén integro-differential equations. The Hallén and Pocklington integral equations are covered by Orfanidis in chapter 24 of the *Electromagnetic Waves and Antennas* book.

You may also become interested in the historical reference on the origins of using integral equations for thin wire antenna design: you'll see it in [On the Integral Equations of Thin Wire Antennas](https://www2.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/1964/ERL-m-79.pdf).

Use the emphasized keywords of my answer, the phrases *Green's function*, *Electromagnetic scattering by a straight thin wire*, and other terminology of the refs from my answer, and your search will return a great many references on antenna design math.